# How to obtain matched text of a regular expression of an Express route

Tags: regex, url, express

If instead of using a string for the route path, I use a regular expression, can I assign matched strings to some variable that I can use in the callback function?

With string:

```
app.get('/user/:id', function(req, res) {
res.send('user id: ' + req.params.id);
});
```

With regexp:

```
var regexp = validUserName();
app.get(regexp, function(req, res) {
  res.send('user id: ' + ?????); //what code should I put here?
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`req.params[n]` contains the contents of the `n`th match group in your regexp.